# What is the regex for an alphanumeric string of length x or of length y?

Tags: javascript, regex

Everything I've come across is for either matching a fixed length, or for being between two different lengths.

For example, this matches all alphanumeric strings **between** lengths 15 and 18:

```
/^([a-zA-Z0-9]){15,18}$/
```

However, I would like to figure out a way to match it to *either* a length of 15 *or* a length of 18.

This is what I picture it looking like, but it is incorrect syntax:

```
/^([a-zA-Z0-9]){15|18}$/
```

Ideally I'd like to avoid repeating the `([a-zA-Z0-9])` part if possible for cleanliness. I am working in JavaScript if that makes a difference here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/^([a-zA-Z0-9]{15}|[a-zA-Z0-9]{18})$/
```

you can also use a case insensitive regex

```
/^([a-z0-9]{15}|[a-z0-9]{18})$/i
```

Comment: Thanks @ic3b3rg, it looks like I'll have to repeat the alphanumeric match part. Not the end of the world!